# Get continuous timestamps of given interval in kibana rollup jobs

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, rollup

I have created a rollup job in `Kibana` as follows:

```
{
    "id": "test-job",
    "index_pattern": "test-index",
    "rollup_index": "test-rollup",
    "cron": "0 * * * * ?",
    "groups": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "interval": "1s",
        "field": "@timestamp",
        "time_zone": "Asia/Colombo"
      },
      "terms": {
        "fields": [
          "transaction"
        ]
      }
    },
    "metrics": [
      {
        "field": "@timestamp",
        "metrics": [
          "value_count"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "timeout": "20s",
    "page_size": 1000
  }
```

Result is as I expected though it doesn't include time stamps which don't include any data on them.

As an example timestamp second of `07:15:45.000` doesn't include any data. So in rollup data also it doesn't include any data.

[image]

But what I want is though any timestamp doesn't include any data it should indicate relevant counts as `0`. Timestamps should appear continuously. There shouldn't be any gaps.

Is this possible using current features of Rollup jobs in Kibana? If yes How could I achieve this?  Hope you understand the question.

Comment: I fulfilled this requirement using a custom python script

Comment: Where 's the script?