# Scripted value field not showing zero values in kibana dashboard area graph?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elk

I have created a scripted field to show data distribution of hours in the day by using a area graph.But the  when i get scripted field to x-axis it don't show the zero values.

Scripted field is

> `["00", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23"][doc['@timestamp'].value.hourOfDay]`

But the result shown in the inspect is as below

> `01 19`
>
> `02 19`
>
> `03 36.4`
>
> `04 19.2`
>
> `05 17.25`
>
> `06 13.25`
>
> `09 16`
>
> `10 154`
>
> `18 6`
>
> `19 20.5`
>
> `20 16.25`
>
> `21 6`
>
> `22 15.75`
>
> `23 19`

You can clearly see there are no values for day 7,8,11,12,13,14,15,16,17. If the value for those days are zero how can i apper it?

Comment: As far as I know Kibana doesn't show values where data doesn't exist. That means if day 7 doesn't have any data, Kibana won't show it as 0. I had a similar problem in different context. See my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57139438/get-continuous-timestamps-of-given-interval-in-kibana-rollup-jobs . What I did was, adding 0 values using a python script.

Comment: But where's the script?

Comment: It is a custom script which won't be aligned with your requirement. you should write your own script. First retrieve data and identify which dates don't have values and write value = 0 to those dates.